# Python: when sending email, always blocked in the clause: smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail

I am writing a Python program to send an email. But every time when executing the clause:

```
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
```

it will block here and always stay the executing status without any prompts and errors. I don't know why. And can anyone help me?

The code is as following:
    import smtplib

```
to = 'toemail@gmail.com'
gmail_user = 'user@gmail.com'
gmail_pwd = 'password'
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo
smtpserver.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
header = 'To:' + to + '\n' + 'From: ' + gmail_user + '\n' + 'Subject:testing \n'
print header
msg = header + '\n this is test msg from mkyong.com \n\n'
smtpserver.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg)
print 'done!'
smtpserver.close()
```

Comment: Is that all of your code? Where's the rest of it (the part where you login, for example).

Comment: ping smtp.gmail.com is successful. But the issue is still there as metioned above.

Comment: Does `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` work? It could be firewall issue.

Answer (score 3):

There may be some issue with the connection (maybe it is being blocked by your proxy or firewall?) and the timeout may be pretty big for you to do not see it going further.

[The documentation of `smtplib.SMTP`](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP) says:

> `class smtplib.SMTP([host[, port[, local_hostname[, timeout]]]])`
>
> (...) An `SMTPConnectError` is raised if the specified `host` doesn’t respond correctly. The optional `timeout` parameter specifies a timeout in seconds for blocking operations like the connection attempt (if not specified, the global default timeout setting will be used).

Try specifying the timeout yourself:

```
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587, timeout=30)
```

Comment: Sorry, the issue is still there as metioned above.

Comment: @Bryant: Others asked this already, but did you ping the server outside the script? In other words: are you able to reach the server? Also: Did you wait at least 40 seconds to see how the script will behave and if it will execute anything after that line? Seemingly the issue is not here, as this must time out after 30 seconds, if unable to connect.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am 4 years late, but this is what worked for me and might help someone else!

```
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587, None, 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference, cpython smtplib is blocking. That is, it blocks the GIL (ie Python) while connecting. Despite the claims the GIL is released on I/O, it is only released on some I/O, and SMTP connections are not such.
To make it async, you need to hand the mail send to another process or thread, depending on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and none of the answers above worked for me. My problem was that since my smtp server uses SSL. I needed to  use `smtplib.SMTP_SSL`
instead of `smtplib.SMTP`. I just posting my full working code below.
Make sure to change values of `req` and `email_config` before executing.

```py
    req = {
        "email": "to@something.com",
        "subject": "new e-mail from python",
        "body": "Hi,\nI am a bot",
    }

    email_config = {
        "server": "smtp.orange.fr",
        "port": 465,
        "username": "username@orange.fr",
        "password": "mypassword",
        "email": "fromwhichemail@orange.fr",
    }
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import smtplib

from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

class Mail(object):
    def __init__(self, email_config):
        self.email = email_config["email"]
        self.password = email_config["password"]
        self.server = email_config["server"]
        self.port = email_config["port"]
        print(f"Logging to {self.server}:{self.port}")
        session = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.server, self.port)
        print(f"Calling ehlo")
        session.ehlo()
        print(f"Calling login")
        session.login(self.email, self.password)
        self.session = session

    def send_message(self, subject, to, body, filename):
        # Create a multipart message and set headers
        message = MIMEMultipart()
        message["From"] = self.email
        message["To"] = to
        message["Subject"] = subject
        message["Bcc"] = ""
        # Add body to email
        message.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain"))
        print(f"tot: {to}")
        print(f"subject: {subject}")
        print(f"body: {body}")

        if filename is not None:
            # Open PDF file in binary mode
            with open(filename, "rb") as attachment:
                part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
                part.set_payload(attachment.read())
            # Encode file in ASCII characters to send by email
            encoders.encode_base64(part)
            # Add header as key/value pair to attachment part
            part.add_header(
                "Content-Disposition",
                f"attachment; filename= {filename}",)
            # Add attachment to message and convert message to string
            message.attach(part)

        # Send e-mail
        print(f"Sending e-mail...")
        self.session.sendmail(self.email, to, message.as_string())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    req = {
        "email": "to@something.com",
        "subject": "new e-mail from python",
        "body": "Hi,\nI am a bot",
    }

    email_config = {
        "server": "smtp.orange.fr",
        "port": 465,
        "username": "username@orange.fr",
        "password": "mypassword",
        "email": "fromwhichemail@orange.fr",
    }
    m = Mail(email_config)
    if "pdf_file" in req:
        m.send_message(req["subject"], req["email"], req["body"], req["pdf_file"])
    else:
        m.send_message(req["subject"], req["email"], req["body"], None)
```