# smtplib can't connect to mailgun

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib

I am trying to send an email in Python but when I try use smtplib it just hangs, until timeout. I'm sure I'm either missing something obvious, or this is caused by a firewall issue. This is the minimal code that reproduces the problem for me

```
from smtplib import SMTP
smtp = SMTP("smtp.mailgun.org", port=25, local_hostname=None, timeout=30)
```

Have I missed something? Or is there some way to tell smtp not to verify SSL/TLS?

If I use requests I can get mailgun to send the mail without a problem:

```
import requests

key = 'MY_API_KEY'
recipient = 'recipient@domain.com'
domain = 'sandboxblablablaredacted.mailgun.org

request_url = r'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/{domain}/messages'
request = requests.post(request_url, 
                        auth=('api', key), 
                        data={
                            'from': 'email@address.com',
                            'to': recipient,
                            'subject': 'Hello',
                            'text': 'Hello from Mailgun'
                        },
                        verify=False,
                       )

print(f'Status: {request.status_code}')
print(f'Body:   {request.text}')
```

note the `verify=False`. Any suggestions on why smtplib won't work?

Comment: What happens if you add a [`timeout` to `SMTP`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11982022/190597)?

Comment: @unutbu I added a 5s timeout and it does raise a time out error. I know when I use the requests library at the office I have set `verfiy=False`. Is there something similar with smtplib? Otherwise I'll just use requests as mailgun offers that as an API anyway

Comment: Perhaps you should be using [port 587](https://www.mailgun.com/blog/which-smtp-port-understanding-ports-25-465-587). You may also need to configure your firewall to do port forwarding on this port.